# add_theme_support( 'title_tag' ) is not showing title on index.php

Tags: functions, title, wp-title

i'm developing a theme.
I read [there](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/2015/08/25/title-tag-support-now-required/) that themes should have the support to title tags declaring it in `functions.php`. I did so, together with removing any title in `head.php`, but my index has no title.

My functions.php has this:

```
add_action("after_setup_theme", "mytheme_setup");

function mytheme_setup () {
    load_theme_textdomain('mytheme');
    add_theme_support( 'title_tag' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size(356, 245);
}
```

Now header.php, very basic atm

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <?php if ( is_singular() && pings_open( get_queried_object() ) ) : ?>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

As final note, i should say that not even the way with `wp_title()` worked. The only way to show something is to put some `bloginfo()` thing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does `echo wp_get_document_title()` output?

Comment: It prints what i'd like to have as title. Should i just put it inside a <title> tag?

Comment: No, that was just a test. That's what ultimately gets called when `wp_head` is invoked, calling all functions hooked to the `wp_head` action. What about `echo current_theme_supports( 'title_tag' )`, what does that output?

Comment: Nothing, not even true or false.

Comment: @Milo Sorry i just seen now. It returns 1. I suppose this is alright.

Comment: Well, there's some disconnect happening somewhere. What about `print_r( $wp_filter['wp_head'] );`, do you see `_wp_render_title_tag` anywhere in there?

Comment: Empty. This time for real.

Comment: oh, If you're in `header.php` you'll probably need `global $wp_filter;` first.

Comment: There we are:  [_wp_render_title_tag] => Array ( [function] => _wp_render_title_tag [accepted_args] => 1 )

Comment: You should be seeing it where the `wp_head()` function is called. Everything seems to be working on its own and it's hooked to fire on `wp_head`.

Comment: So no ideas about what may be wrong?

Comment: Sorry, no. If you don't already have it enabled, [enable debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and make sure there are no errors reported.

Comment: At this point i'll do. Thanks for the time you spent.

Comment: Subtle, but dangerous. I wrote "title_tag" in my functions.php, but it is title-tag. Of course it wouldn't work...

Comment: oh that's unfortunate, ha. glad you finally got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a typo in funcions.php, typing `title_tag` instead of `title-tag`.

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of wordpress you are using. If its older version then you need Backwards Compatibility as mentioned here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag

Also make sure to switch theme again.

Comment: Version 4.7.4. Compatible as far as i know.